# I got multiple entry schengen visa issued by Greece.. Can I directly travel from India - Qatar - Romania or through schengen state

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, romania, greece

I got multiple entry schengen visa issued by Greece.. Can I directly travel from India - Qatar - Romania or should I have stamping in schengen state?

Answer (score 1):

the romanian foreign affairs embassy says explicitly : 
**The holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, of national visas or residence permits issued by Schengen States are not required a Romanian visa to enter, transit or stay on the territory of Romania for 90 days in any 180-day period. Therefore, you can travel to Romania without a visa only if you hold a valid Schengen visa with at least two entries**